# How can JSON column formatting be used to highlight duplicate entries in a column a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, column-formatting, person-or-group

Column formatting is used in SharePoint Online to customize how fields in lists are displayed. Microsoft provide [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) regarding the use of JSON for column formatting.

As is described in the documentation, this works well for basic things such as adding a class depending on the name of the current *field*. For example:

```
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField == 'Done', 'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField == 'In progress', 'sp-field-severity--low', if(@currentField == 'In review', 'sp-field-severity--warning', if(@currentField == 'Has issues', 'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', 'sp-field-severity--blocked')))) + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
  },
```

The end result being:

[image: Column formatting on the status of a column]

However, is there a way to check values in the current *column* and apply a class or color to duplicate entries in that column?

For example, if there is a Person column entitled **Participants**. One list entry has the value, `Smith, John`. If another entry gets created and `Smith, John` is added again, both of these values would be highlighted or have a class applied.

Comment: Do you want to check every field for duplication or only few fields?

Comment: @harshalgite, every field in one column. For example, if the column is 'Participants'. It would highlight if the same participant was listed twice. I edited my post and added that example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

In column formatting, you cannot access/use the column values from another list item/row.

You can only access the column values from the same list item/row like `[$AnotherColumnFromSameRow]`.

Where `AnotherColumnFromSameRow` is internal name another column from same list item/row.

You can get the internal name of your list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: In this case, it is the *same* list but checking against values inside one column. So it is checking duplicate values inside the same column. Would this still apply?

Comment: No, it is not possible in column formatting. column formatting can access the column values from same entry only. it cannot access column values from different entries(same list - different entry/item).